# How to use dynamic json value on my POJO class with Gson?

Tags: java, android, pojo, jsonschema2pojo, gson

```
{
"localeCode": "",
"map": {
    "DynamicName1": [],
    "DynamicName2": [
        {
            "date": "2016-05-15T00:00:00",
            "seqId": 1,
            "status": 10
        },
        {
            "date": "2016-05-16T00:00:00",
            "seqId": 83,
            "status": 10
        }
    ],
    "DynamicName3": [],
    "DynamicName4": []
},
"respCode": 100,
"respMsg": "success",
"status": 1
}
```

How to correctly map this kind of json. If you can see that, `Dynamic` is a dynamic name. So far I have done this :

```
public class MapModel {

public MapObject map;

public static class MapObject{
    public java.util.Map<String, Student> queryStudent;

    public static class Student{
        public String date;
        public String seqId;
        public String status;
    }
}
}
```

But when run the app. I'm getting `NullPointerException`. Can somebody help me?

Comment: check this answer, it shows how to get the keys in an object, i think you have to do it manually , to get all keys in "map" and iterate over http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31094305/java-gson-getting-the-list-of-all-keys-under-a-jsonobject

Answer (score 3):

You're getting the `NullPointerException` accessing `queryStudent` of your `MapObject` inside your `MapModel` since it's not correctly filled when you're trying to deserialize your *Json*.

So to solve your problem look at [*Gson documentation*](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Generic-Types) where you can see:

> You can serialize the collection with Gson without doing anything
>   specific: toJson(collection) would write out the desired output.
>
> However, deserialization with fromJson(json, Collection.class) will
>   not work since Gson has no way of knowing how to map the input to the
>   types. Gson requires that you provide a genericised version of
>   collection type in fromJson(). So, you have three options:
>
> 1. Use Gson's parser API (low-level streaming parser or the DOM parser
>      JsonParser) to parse the array elements and then use Gson.fromJson()
>      on each of the array elements.This is the preferred approach. Here is
>      an example that demonstrates how to do this.
> 2. Register a type adapter for Collection.class that looks at each of the
>      array members and maps them to appropriate objects. The disadvantage
>      of this approach is that it will screw up deserialization of other
>      collection types in Gson.
> 3. Register a type adapter for MyCollectionMemberType and use fromJson()
>      with Collection.

Since your `MapObject` containts a `java.util.Map` but your class itself it's not generic, I think that a good approach for your case is create a `Deserializer`.

Before this try to clean up your class definition, to provide constructors to make the deserializer easy to build. Your *POJO* classes could be:

*Student class*

```
public class Student{
  public String date;
  public String seqId;
  public String status;

  public Student(String date, String seqId, String status){
      this.date = date;
      this.seqId = seqId;
      this.status = status;
  }
}
```

*MapObject class*

Note: I change you `Map` definition, since in your *Json* seems that could be multiple students for each `DynamicName` (look at `DynamicName2` from your question), so I use `Map<String,List<Student>>` instead of `Map<String,Student>`:

```
public class MapObject{
   public Map<String,List<Student>> queryStudent;

   public MapObject(Map<String,List<Student>> value){
       this.queryStudent = value;
   }
}
```

*MapModel class*

```
public class MapModel {
     public MapObject map;     
}
```

Now create a `Deserializer` for your `MapObject`:

```
public class MapObjectDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<MapObject> {
  public MapObject deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
      throws JsonParseException {

      Map<String,List<Student>> queryStudents = new HashMap<String,List<Student>>();
      // for each DynamicElement...
      for (Map.Entry<String,JsonElement> entry : json.getAsJsonObject().entrySet()) {

          List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
          // each dynamicElement has an Array so convert  and add an student
          // for each array entry
          for(JsonElement elem : entry.getValue().getAsJsonArray()){
              students.add(new Gson().fromJson(elem,Student.class));
          }
          // put the dinamic name and student on the map
          queryStudents.put(entry.getKey(),students);
      }
      // finally create the mapObject
      return new MapObject(queryStudents);
  }
}
```

Finally register the `Deserializer` and parse your *Json*:

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.registerTypeAdapter(MapObject.class, new MapObjectDeserializer());
Gson gson = builder.create();
MapModel object = gson.fromJson(YourJson,MapModel.class);
```

DISCLAIMER: For fast prototyping I test this using *groovy*, I try to keep the *Java* syntax but I can forget something, anyway I think that this can put you on the right direction.

Hope it helps,