# Add a list of objects to an arraylist from a webservice call

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am using a public API that gives me a list of Objects but they not in a ArrayList as below:

FYI this is just a portion of the JSON Response.

FYI 2: This is already being parsed using Gson from Retrofit

```
"dataCenters": {
        "Peru": {
            "capacity": "full",
            "load": "idle"
        },
        "EU West": {
            "capacity": "full",
            "load": "low"
        }
  }
```

As you can see the dataCenters object is not a list. How would I be able to add this list of objects to an arraylist?

I have made all the dataCenters the same type of object called DataCentersStatus so that i dont have a long list of different models that all are basically the same just have different names.

Thank you

Comment: first get JSONObject("dataCenters); then get its length and by that you can do as you want

Comment: You can find more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31094305/java-gson-getting-the-list-of-all-keys-under-a-jsonobject

Comment: Json without wrapper. It is not valid then.

Comment: `Invalid JSON `.

Comment: this is a portion of the json, the question is not about whether its a json or not?

Comment: Did you try `JsonParser` mentioned in my link?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention that i am already parsing the json using GSON that is found in Retrofit

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using gson.

```
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    JsonElement element = parser.parse(jsonAsString);
    JsonElement dataCenters = element.getAsJsonObject().get("dataCenters");
    Set<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> entries = dataCenters.getAsJsonObject().entrySet();
    List<DataCenter> list = new LinkedList<>();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry: entries) {
        DataCenter dc = gson.fromJson(entry.getValue(), DataCenter.class); 
        dc.setName(entry.getKey());
        list.add(dc);
    }
```

`DataCenter` is a class with fields `name`, `capacity` and `load`.

More information you can find [here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/).

Maven dependency

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention that i am already parsing the json using GSON that is found in Retrofit

Comment: The problem is that its not a List<DataCenters> but an object that hold a set of objects. I just want to know how i can put those objects into a list efficiently

Comment: Anyway, if it is possible you should redesing your JSON.

Comment: its not a json that i am sending? its a api that is available to the public