# how to read value key form a Json Element in Java

Tags: java

I have a jsonElement as following 
how can I retrieve "value2" with minimal amount of coding?

```
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": "value3"
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31094305/java-gson-getting-the-list-of-all-keys-under-a-jsonobject

Comment: javaee standard : jsonB ,mostly used : jackson

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: By getting the value for `"key2"`?

Comment: jsonElement? from the gson library?

Answer (score 1):

Add jar in your project : **org.json**.

Suppose that you are having string,

```
String yourString = "{ \"key1\": \"value1\",\"key2\": \"value2\",\"key3\":\"value3\" }"

JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(yourString);
```

First of all, check the desired key which you want to access to avoid nullPointer exception , then access you value . i.e.

**Note**: It is always a good practice to check whether this exists but in your case not mandatory

```
if(jsonObj.contains("key2") {  

 String key2 = jsonObj.getString("key2");
}
```

Comment: seems fine now.