# How to convert json key as attribute in java

Tags: java, json

I'm very new working java with json. Couldn't find relevant solutions. That's why posting this question. I have json with property name as value in it. How to convert this property name as attribute and restructured in array. Any help would be much appreciated.

Following is my json file:

***INPUT JSON:***

```
{
    "payload": {
        "giata": {
            "435185": [
                "2019-11-27T14:34:32.368197Z"
            ]
        },
        "dod1": {
            "A0947863": [
                "2019-11-27T14:34:32.368197Z"
            ]
        },
        "gr": {
            "A0947863": [
                "2019-11-27T14:34:32.368197Z",
                "2021-04-27T06:13:12.841968Z",
                "2021-04-27T06:13:21.640612Z",
                "2021-04-27T06:13:28.439001Z",
                "2021-04-27T06:13:43.487103Z",
                "2021-04-27T06:13:49.770269Z"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

***Expected JSON :***

```
{
    "payload": {
        "sources": [
            {
                "source": "giata",
                "code": "435185",
                "version": [
                    "2019-11-27T14:34:32.368197Z"
                ]
            },
            {
                "source": "dod1",
                "code": "A0947863",
                "version": [
                    "2019-11-27T14:34:32.368197Z"
                ]
            },
            {
                "source": "gr",
                "code": "A0947863",
                "version": [
                    "2019-11-27T14:34:32.368197Z",
                    "2021-04-27T06:13:12.841968Z",
                    "2021-04-27T06:13:21.640612Z",
                    "2021-04-27T06:13:28.439001Z",
                    "2021-04-27T06:13:43.487103Z",
                    "2021-04-27T06:13:49.770269Z"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Code**:

```
package com.tui.structure_json;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        String yourJson = "{\r\n" + 
                "   \"payload\": {\r\n" + 
                "       \"giata\": {\r\n" + 
                "           \"435185\": [\r\n" + 
                "               \"2019-11-27T14:34:32.368197Z\"\r\n" + 
                "           ]\r\n" + 
                "       },\r\n" + 
                "       \"dod1\": {\r\n" + 
                "           \"A0947863\": [\r\n" + 
                "               \"2019-11-27T14:34:32.368197Z\"\r\n" + 
                "           ]\r\n" + 
                "       },\r\n" + 
                "       \"gr\": {\r\n" + 
                "           \"A0947863\": [\r\n" + 
                "               \"2019-11-27T14:34:32.368197Z\",\r\n" + 
                "               \"2021-04-27T06:13:12.841968Z\",\r\n" + 
                "               \"2021-04-27T06:13:21.640612Z\",\r\n" + 
                "               \"2021-04-27T06:13:28.439001Z\",\r\n" + 
                "               \"2021-04-27T06:13:43.487103Z\",\r\n" + 
                "               \"2021-04-27T06:13:49.770269Z\"\r\n" + 
                "           ]\r\n" + 
                "       }\r\n" + 
                "   }\r\n" + 
                "}";
        JsonElement element = JsonParser.parseString(yourJson);
        JsonObject obj = element.getAsJsonObject(); //since you know it's a JsonObject
        Set<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> entries = obj.entrySet();//will return members of your object
        for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry: entries) {
            System.out.println(entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend parsing it, mapping it, then serialising it again.

Comment: @HenryTwist Thanks for response. Dynamic parsing can be done through json path?  Any pseudo code or references will be helpful?

Comment: I've actually just noticed that your expected JSON isn't actually valid JSON, the array isn't an array? So maybe update that to what you actually want and then I'll take another look.

Comment: @HenryTwist I have updated the input and expected json. Please have a look.

Comment: I would take a look at this answer which includes steps that parse the JSON keys, which is what you need here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31094365/10082297

Comment: mapping I feel some what challenging.

Answer (score 0):

You may try library *Josson* to do the transformation.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

**Deserialization**

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "    \"payload\": {" +
    "        \"giata\": {" +
    "            \"435185\": [" +
    "                \"2019-11-27T14:34:32.368197Z\"" +
    "            ]" +
    "        }," +
    "        \"dod1\": {" +
    "            \"A0947863\": [" +
    "                \"2019-11-27T14:34:32.368197Z\"" +
    "            ]" +
    "        }," +
    "        \"gr\": {" +
    "            \"A0947863\": [" +
    "                \"2019-11-27T14:34:32.368197Z\"," +
    "                \"2021-04-27T06:13:12.841968Z\"," +
    "                \"2021-04-27T06:13:21.640612Z\"," +
    "                \"2021-04-27T06:13:28.439001Z\"," +
    "                \"2021-04-27T06:13:43.487103Z\"," +
    "                \"2021-04-27T06:13:49.770269Z\"" +
    "            ]" +
    "        }" +
    "    }" +
    "}");
```

**Transformation**

```
JsonNode node = josson.getNode(
    "map(payload" +
    "  .map(sources: entries()" +
    "    .map(source: key," +
    "         code: value.keys().[0]," +
    "         version: value.toArray().[0]" +
    "    )" +
    "  )" +
    ")");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

**Output**

```
{
  "payload" : {
    "sources" : [ {
      "source" : "giata",
      "code" : "435185",
      "version" : [ "2019-11-27T14:34:32.368197Z" ]
    }, {
      "source" : "dod1",
      "code" : "A0947863",
      "version" : [ "2019-11-27T14:34:32.368197Z" ]
    }, {
      "source" : "gr",
      "code" : "A0947863",
      "version" : [ "2019-11-27T14:34:32.368197Z", "2021-04-27T06:13:12.841968Z", "2021-04-27T06:13:21.640612Z", "2021-04-27T06:13:28.439001Z", "2021-04-27T06:13:43.487103Z", "2021-04-27T06:13:49.770269Z" ]
    } ]
  }
}
```